# Let $\textbf r(t) =\langle 1 + 3\cos(t), 4\cos(t), −1 + 5\sin(t)\rangle$. Find an equation for a sphere that this curve lies on.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

As it says in the title, any help would be greatly appreciated. I've tried some things but just can't get it to click.

Comment: $(x-1)^2+y^2+(z+1)^2=25$

Comment: Hint: $(x-1)^2 + y^2 = 25 \cos^2(t)$. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$r(t)$ defines a curve in $3$-dimensions as a functions of every real $t$ from $\mathbb R$ onto $\mathbb R^3$. We will have to get rid of its parameter $t$ solving  the following system of equations:

$ x = 1+3\cos(t) $

$ y = 4\cos(t)$

$ z = -1 + 5\sin(t)$

Do squares over all the equations:

$ (x -1)^2 = 9 \cos^2(t) $

$ y^2 = 16 \cos^2(t)$

$ (z+1)^2 = 25 \sin^2(t)$

Now add the three of them together:

$ (x -1)^2 + y^2 + (z+1)^2  = 9 \cos^2(t) + 16 \cos^2(t) + 25 \sin^2(t)$

Applying $\cos^2(u) + \sin^2(u) =1 $ for every real number.

$(x-1)^2 + y^2 + (z+1)^2  = 25$

The last equation defines a sphere of radius $5$ and center $(1,0,-1)$ in $3$D space.

Comment: Ah, I see! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

$$ \vec{r(t) }  = \langle1 , 0 ,-1\rangle +\langle 3 \cos t , 4 \cos t , 5 \sin t\rangle$$

And,

$$ |\langle 3 \cos t , 4 \cos t + 5 \sin t\rangle | = \sqrt{ ( 3 \cos t)^2 + (4 \cos t)^2 + (5 \sin t)^2} = 5$$

So we have that no matter what the value of $t$ is the second term is at a distance of $5$ from the point $\langle1,0,-1\rangle$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Or I can use the distance formula! r=5, with a center at (1,0,-1). Thank you!